# Function not being executed

Tags: javascript, html

**EDIT: I've updated the function and this was taken from**

http://www.scriptiny.com/2011/01/javascript-fade-in-out/

So in my web page I have an image, and two buttons. What I'd like to accomplish is when the first button is clicked then the image changes to another one (this is working) and then I'd like for that image to fade. I have a function that takes an object and makes it fade away but for some reason it is not working. I then tried adding that function to a button but even when the button is clicked the image (both the old and the new one) don't change.

I first **display the image** like so.

```
<img id="chestImg" border="0" src="img/chestClosed.png" alt="Chest!">
```

and then I have the **button to change the image** which looks like the following.

```
<button id="openChest" onclick='changeImage("chestImg","img/chestO.gif");' > Open Chest! </button>
```

The **changeImage** function looks like this

```
function changeImage(obj,img) {
    document.getElementById(obj).src = img;
}
```

And then the **fade function** looks like this.

```
var fadeEffect=function(){
    return{
        init:function(id, flag, target){
                this.elem = document.getElementById(id);
            clearInterval(this.elem.si);
            this.target = target ? target : flag ? 100 : 0;
            this.flag = flag || -1;
            this.alpha = this.elem.style.opacity ? parseFloat(this.elem.style.opacity) * 100 : 0;
            this.elem.si = setInterval(function(){fadeEffect.tween()}, 20);
        },
        tween:function(){
            if(this.alpha == this.target){
                clearInterval(this.elem.si);
            }else{
                var value = Math.round(this.alpha + ((this.target - this.alpha) * .05)) + (1 * this.flag);
                this.elem.style.opacity = value / 100;
                this.elem.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + value + ')';
                this.alpha = value
            }
        }
    }
}();
```

**Solution Fix Attempt One**

I tried adding a call to the **fade function** after the **changeImage** function so it would look like this.

```
function changeImage(obj,img) {
    document.getElementById(obj).src = img;
    fadeEffect.init('chestImg', 0)
}
```

**Solution Fix Attempt Two**

But that didn't work so I tried adding it to a button like so. **Note In the end I would not like a button for the fade function but it being ran after the image is changed**.

```
<button id="openChest" onclick='fadeEffect.init('chestImg', 0)' > Hide </button>
```

**The two images look like the following:**

The first is a .png file

[image]

And the second is a **.gif file** that was edited so that instead of constantly looping it would **loop only once**.

[image]

**Solution Attempt #1**

I tried making a method like

```
function fade(obj) {
    obj.fadeOut(500);
}
```

And then calling it like so,

```
<button id="openChest" onclick="fade('chestImg')" > Hide </button>
```

But that didn't work.

Comment: well `onclick='fadeEffect.init('chestImg', 0)'` has quote problems

Comment: Should it be like ' onclick="fadeEffect.init('chestImg', 0)" '? Because that still doesn't work.

Comment: @user2612619: You may want to take a look at this link http://jsfiddle.net/HhpW5/5/

Comment: @IsaacLem I tried making a function that uses '    obj.fadeOut(500);' but that didn't work.

Comment: You are calling the function immediately with () and are returning the "result" to the variable, am totally unsure if this works. Do a console.log(fadeEffect)!

Comment: I made a fiddle for you http://jsfiddle.net/2ZZ9c/ What is it supposed to do exactly?

Comment: @dollarvar Didn't work.

Comment: @epascarello When the button is clicked the img should change to the .gif and the fade away.

Comment: What do you mean, the console.log (or my answer)? Does it give you the objects as return or what? ;)

Comment: @dollarvar Both the console.log and the answer don't work. I'm supposed to add it at the end of the function?

Comment: The console.log should be after the variable block. Do you not get an error in the console, there is an ; missing after this.alpha=value; ?!?

Comment: An error in what console? And I added the ';'. Also when adding your code the page doesn't work.

Comment: Eaah, the console in chrome or firefox. Either right mouse button in chrome "inspect element" or firefox I guess, something with "inspect with firebug". Then the console tab.

Comment: Oh, yes, I missed a bracket to delete after the function delete, I am sorry, I am on an iPad, lost overview. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Am i totally off, or should it be

```
var fadeEffect={
    init:function(id, flag, target){
        this.elem = document.getElementById(id);
        clearInterval(this.elem.si);
        this.target = target ? target : flag ? 100 : 0;
        this.flag = flag || -1;
        this.alpha = this.elem.style.opacity ? parseFloat(this.elem.style.opacity) * 100 : 0;
        this.elem.si = setInterval(function(){fadeEffect.tween()}, 20);
    },
    tween:function(){
        if(this.alpha == this.target){
            clearInterval(this.elem.si);
        }else{
            var value = Math.round(this.alpha + ((this.target - this.alpha) * .05)) + (1 * this.flag);
            this.elem.style.opacity = value / 100;
            this.elem.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + value + ')';
            this.alpha = value;
        }
    }
};
```

?

Comment: That does not work, in fact when adding that nothing else works, so I'm assuming there is a problem in it.

Comment: This time the page is fine but nothing happens when I click hide.

Comment: @user2612619 Did you find the console?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't say anything when "hide" is clicked.

Comment: You only used quite complicated javascript code in your first part, but then fadeOut is a jQuery function, may I ask if you have it "installed"? :)

Comment: I do not have "jQuery" installed.

Comment: @user2612619 Then you either have to write a likewise complicated javascript version for "hide" or google for "google jquery api" and link to it. ;) :)

Answer (score 0):

Well at the very least, only one of these will work in a browser and the other two should throw errors.

```
    this.elem.style.opacity = value / 100;
    this.elem.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + value + ')';
    this.alpha = value
```

Better to check existence for which property works and then define a function with the same name that adjusts the appropriate property. But for now. Try just using opacity in chrome.

Comment: I've updated the original code for the function in the post. Now when it's clicked the img will flash. And I've posted where I got it from as I re-found it. My code is just like theirs.